# How can I remove the space at the top of this Xamarin grid layout?

Tags: android, xaml, xamarin.forms

I have a requirement for a nest of square buttons on a remote control app and after several attempts, created the following content page and class.

How might I get rid of the space AT THE TOP of the grid please (shown in red on the screenshot)?

**Content page**

```
     <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Black" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">

      <Label x:Name="MyAwesomeLabel" FontSize="60" FontAttributes="Bold"  Text="Label" TextColor="White" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"  LineBreakMode="NoWrap" BackgroundColor="Blue" Margin="12, 12, 12, 0"/>

      <Grid x:Name="MyAwesomeGrid" RowSpacing="1" ColumnSpacing="1" Padding="0, -40, 0, 0" Margin="0" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Red">

          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
               <RowDefinition Height="1"/>
               <RowDefinition Height="1"/>
               <RowDefinition Height="1"/>
               <RowDefinition Height="1"/>
               <RowDefinition Height="1"/>
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>

          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
               <ColumnDefinition Width="1"/>
               <ColumnDefinition Width="1"/>
               <ColumnDefinition Width="1"/>
               <ColumnDefinition Width="1"/>
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

          <ImageButton Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Source="A.xml"/>
          <ImageButton Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Source="B.xml"/>
          <ImageButton Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Source="C.xml"/>
          <ImageButton Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Source="D.xml"/>

          <ImageButton Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Source="E.xml"/>   
          <ImageButton Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Source="F.xml"/>
          <ImageButton Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Source="G.xml"/>
          <ImageButton Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" Source="H.xml"/>

          <ImageButton Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Source="I.xml"/>
          <ImageButton Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Source="J.xml"/>
          <ImageButton Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" Source="K.xml"/>
          <ImageButton Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3" Source="L.xml"/>

          <ImageButton Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Source="M.xml"/>   
          <ImageButton Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Source="N.xml"/>
          <ImageButton Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" Source="O.xml"/>
          <ImageButton Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="3" Source="P.xml"/>

          <ImageButton Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" Source="Q.xml"/>
          <ImageButton Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" Source="R.xml"/>
          <ImageButton Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="2" Source="S.xml"/>
          <ImageButton Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="3" Source="T.xml"/>
      </Grid>
 </StackLayout>
```

**Page class**

```
      public MyAwesomeApp()
  {
       InitializeComponent();
       double size = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Width / 12;
       foreach(ColumnDefinition col in buttons.ColumnDefinitions)
       {
            col.Width = size;
       }
       foreach(RowDefinition row in buttons.RowDefinitions)
       {
            row.Height = size;
       }
  }
```

**Result**

[image: MyAwesomeApp screenshot]

The grid background colour is red so the space is definitely part of the grid.

Comment: set the Spacing on your StackLayout to 0

Comment: you also have VerticalOptions set to EndAndExpand

Comment: Thanks @Jason.
I did this: <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Black" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" Spacing="0"> but I still have a big red space.

Comment: Your Grid is not big enough to fill the empty space, so something has to fill it.  You can try setting one of your grid rows to auto instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your culprit

You started with **Row="1"** instead of **Row="0"**

```
<ImageButton Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Source="A.xml"/>
```

The space at top is of row 0 , ***Grid automatically created row no 6*** , now your page has 6 rows instead of 5.

change 1 to 0, 2 to 1 and so on .. and you will get the desired result and remove the negative padding it is no longer required.

```
<ImageButton Grid.Row="0" HeightRequest="{Binding Width, Source={x:Reference btn1}}" Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="LightBlue"/>
...
<ImageButton Grid.Row="1" HeightRequest="{Binding Width, Source={x:Reference btn1}}" Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="LightBlue"/>
...
<ImageButton Grid.Row="2" HeightRequest="{Binding Width, Source={x:Reference btn1}}" Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="LightBlue"/>
...
<ImageButton Grid.Row="3" HeightRequest="{Binding Width, Source={x:Reference btn1}}" Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="LightBlue"/>
...
<ImageButton Grid.Row="4" HeightRequest="{Binding Width, Source={x:Reference btn1}}" Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="LightBlue"/>
```

Comment: Shubham, thank you.
There used to be another label in row 0.
This answers my question perfectly (although now the app doesn't fill the whole screen).
I rejected your edit because I felt I should show the actual code I had tried.

Comment: @sanepete app fill issue post another question for that and I'll try to answer it

Comment: Shubham, I'm going to have a go at fixing it myself first.
Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the size of **ImageButton** by using View-to-View binding . So that you don't need to set it in code behind any more .

```
<StackLayout BackgroundColor="Black" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">

        <Label x:Name="MyAwesomeLabel" FontSize="60" FontAttributes="Bold"  Text="Label" TextColor="White" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"  LineBreakMode="NoWrap" BackgroundColor="Blue" Margin="12, 12, 12, 0"/>

        <Grid x:Name="MyAwesomeGrid" RowSpacing="1" ColumnSpacing="1" Padding="1"  HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Red">

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <ImageButton x:Name="btn1" HeightRequest="{Binding Width, Source={x:Reference btn1}}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="LightBlue"/>
            <ImageButton Grid.Row="0" HeightRequest="{Binding Width, Source={x:Reference btn1}}" Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="LightBlue"/>
            <ImageButton Grid.Row="0" HeightRequest="{Binding Width, Source={x:Reference btn1}}" Grid.Column="2" BackgroundColor="LightBlue"/>
            <ImageButton Grid.Row="0" HeightRequest="{Binding Width, Source={x:Reference btn1}}" Grid.Column="3" BackgroundColor="LightBlue"/>

            <ImageButton Grid.Row="1" HeightRequest="{Binding Width, Source={x:Reference btn1}}" Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="LightBlue"/>
            <ImageButton Grid.Row="1" HeightRequest="{Binding Width, Source={x:Reference btn1}}" Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="LightBlue"/>
            <ImageButton Grid.Row="1" HeightRequest="{Binding Width, Source={x:Reference btn1}}" Grid.Column="2" BackgroundColor="LightBlue"/>
            <ImageButton Grid.Row="1" HeightRequest="{Binding Width, Source={x:Reference btn1}}" Grid.Column="3" BackgroundColor="LightBlue"/>

            <ImageButton Grid.Row="2" HeightRequest="{Binding Width, Source={x:Reference btn1}}" Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="LightBlue"/>
            <ImageButton Grid.Row="2" HeightRequest="{Binding Width, Source={x:Reference btn1}}" Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="LightBlue"/>
            <ImageButton Grid.Row="2" HeightRequest="{Binding Width, Source={x:Reference btn1}}" Grid.Column="2" BackgroundColor="LightBlue"/>
            <ImageButton Grid.Row="2" HeightRequest="{Binding Width, Source={x:Reference btn1}}" Grid.Column="3" BackgroundColor="LightBlue"/>

            <ImageButton Grid.Row="3" HeightRequest="{Binding Width, Source={x:Reference btn1}}" Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="LightBlue"/>
            <ImageButton Grid.Row="3" HeightRequest="{Binding Width, Source={x:Reference btn1}}" Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="LightBlue"/>
            <ImageButton Grid.Row="3" HeightRequest="{Binding Width, Source={x:Reference btn1}}" Grid.Column="2" BackgroundColor="LightBlue"/>
            <ImageButton Grid.Row="3" HeightRequest="{Binding Width, Source={x:Reference btn1}}" Grid.Column="3" BackgroundColor="LightBlue"/>

            <ImageButton Grid.Row="4" HeightRequest="{Binding Width, Source={x:Reference btn1}}" Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="LightBlue"/>
            <ImageButton Grid.Row="4" HeightRequest="{Binding Width, Source={x:Reference btn1}}" Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="LightBlue"/>
            <ImageButton Grid.Row="4" HeightRequest="{Binding Width, Source={x:Reference btn1}}" Grid.Column="2" BackgroundColor="LightBlue"/>
            <ImageButton Grid.Row="4" HeightRequest="{Binding Width, Source={x:Reference btn1}}" Grid.Column="3" BackgroundColor="LightBlue"/>
        </Grid>
    </StackLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: but now the space is below all the remaining height after the label needs to be utilized

Comment: Just remove everything and just keep the grid on the whole page, there will be that space at the top, why is that

Comment: Which effect did you want to achieve ?

Comment: see my answer @lucas